# if else condition using three models rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I have 3 models

Users: id , name

Jobs: id, user_id, title

Applications: id, job_id, user_id

In Job#show page I am trying to put a button which is visible only to people who haven't applied to the job, haven't created the job and are logged in . I am using devise. I have managed to build correct relationship in these models (thanks to SO) as following.

user.jobs #list all jobs posted by the user

jobs.applicants #list all applicants on the job

Question is how to formulate if else condtion which shows button which submits a form (hidden) to the job#show page and puts job_id and user_id in the application model.

I tried

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
 <% if job.user_id = current_user.id %>
   <div style="text-align:center;" class="widget">
    <%= link_to(new_user_session_path, :class => "g-btn type_primary") do %>
      <i class="icon-external-link"></i> Apply for the job 
    <% end %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I can't seems to get the idea on how to get around error of object.id nil.

Comment: if job.user_id = current_user.id   is an assignment , not a compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how does a user apply for the job?  using what controller?

you code has the user logging in again,

does the user need to create an application object and does it require additional information from the user to complete the process, or is more along the lines of send existing information from the user to information stored in the job.

If the latter you can do something like this.

```
resources :jobs do
      member do
        post 'apply'
      end
end

<% if user_signed_in? %>
 <% unless job.user == current_user %>
   <div style="text-align:center;" class="widget">
    <%= link_to 'Apply', apply_job_path(job), method: :post %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Sign in to apply', new_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
```

then in your jobs controller

```
def apply
  if Application.create job_id: params[:job_id], user: current_user
    redirect_to jobs_path,  notice: "You have applied, good luck!"
  else
    ... do something for failure... 
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have missed an `=` sign.

You can improve your if condition like this

```
<% if user_signed_in? && job.present? && job.user_id == current_user.id %>
    your logic here
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if job.user_id == current_user.id %> 
    <div style="text-align:center;" class="widget">
      <%= link_to "Apply for the job" new_user_session_path, :class => "g-btn type_primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

and it might be better to change this line

```
<div style="text-align:center;" class="widget">
```

to

```
<div class="widget center">
```

and add a class named `center` to the relevant css sheet

Comment: if job.user_id = current_user.id  <-- that is an assignment, not a compare